# Using pickmeup datepicker event listeners inside document.ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, pickmeup

The pickmeup docs provide examples of using event listeners with pure javascript, but how would you apply these when jquery is available and ready?

```
pickmeup(element);
element.addEventListener('pickmeup-change', function (e) {
    console.log(e.detail.formatted_date); // New date according to current format
    console.log(e.detail.date);           // New date as Date object
})
```

The following does not seem to work:

```
  $('#pickup_date').on('pickmeup-change', function (e) {
        console.log(e.detail.formatted_date); // New date according to current format
        console.log(e.detail.date);           // New date as Date object
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer this, the event listen needs to be included in the selector initialization:

```
  $('#pickup_date').pickmeup({
    format : 'm/d/Y',
    hide_on_select: true,
    calendars : 2,
    change : function (formatted_date) {
       $('#return_date').val(addDays(formatted_date,2));
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery event docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/): "To access event properties not listed above, use the `event.originalEvent` object". In other words, use `e.originalEvent.detail.formatted_date` and `e.originalEvent.detail.date`.

Answer (score 0):

I took a mistake $(...).pickmeup is not a function